# I'm not exactly sure what this x86 Add instruction is doing

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I'm not exactly sure what this `add` instruction is doing:

```
add 0x0(%rbp,%rbx,4),%eax
```

If it were:

```
add %rbx,%eax
```

I know it would add the contents of `rbx` and the contents in `eax` and store them back into `eax`. However, the `0x0(%rbp,%rbx,4)` is throwing me off.

Comment: For reference: [Address operand syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because it's stupid&confusing AT&T syntax.
In normal Intel syntax it's `add eax,dword ptr[rbp+4*rbx+0]` ie add the dword at rbp+4*rbx to eax.