# x86 AT&T | What does `add` instruction do? (using memory addressing)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I have a simple instruction `add $100, 100(%eax, %edx, 8)`

I understand that `100(%eax, %edx, 8)` resolves to the memory address `100+%eax+(%edx*8)` but what I fail to understand is, does it add 100 to this address OR to the value stored at this address.

**Issues**

1. In AT&T `src, dest` is the order. So technically `100(%eax, %edx, 8)` should be the destination
2. Now, it should technically add to the address (and not the value at that addr) but it does not make intuitive sense
3. Am I wrong to say `100(%eax, %edx, 8)` resolves to `100+%eax+(%edx*8)` and is it rather that it resolves to `(100+%eax+(%edx*8))`? Where the outer brackets are dereferencing the address inside it?

**Resources I tried checking already**

1. Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2 (2A, 2B, 2C & 2D): Instruction Set Reference, A-Z
2. http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-zen-of-asm/#mov-move-copy-right-operand-into-left-operand
3. [I'm not exactly sure what this x86 Add instruction is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544672/im-not-exactly-sure-what-this-x86-add-instruction-is-doing)
4. [x86 Assembly Memory - What does the "add" instruction do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887105/x86-assembly-memory-what-does-the-add-instruction-do)
5. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-19/index.html
6. http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory

Do note, I have not read all of these completely. I do not understand the way they explain perhaps. It is my humble request for you to put it in as much simplicity and detail as possible

Comment: Your point (2) is wrong: `add $100, 100(%eax, %edx, 8)` adds to the value at that address, not the address itself.  I wonder where you got that wrong information from. (3) is wrong too.  The address is `100 + eax + edx * 8` the parentheses are just syntactical, they don't mean anything.

Comment: @fuz In 3rd, won't you be needing the outer `()`? As they are for dereferencing. If you do not use them, how will add instruction understand that it has to be the `value at that address`?

Comment: What it would mean to add 100 to the address? After adding 100 to the address, then what would happen with the result of the addition?

Comment: `addl $100, 55` adds 100 to the dword at absolute address `55`.  Unlike NASM syntax, AT&T doesn't always need `()` for a memory operand.  Displacements go outside the parens, those are only for registers.   Also note that the address-size suffix is required: plain `add` is ambiguous between byte, word, dword, (and qword in 64-bit mode) operand-size.

Comment: Found a duplicate that picks apart a complex AT&T addressing mode into its parts with run-time add.  The stuff outside the `()` is just the `disp8` / `disp32` part of the addressing mode.